# Relation of length of a projection of a point to a line

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles

In the given figure, can it be said that $x \leq a + b - d$?
[image: problem image]

Comment: Going to the extreme with sliding $P$ further and further out along $d$, I'd say no.

Comment: But you could have other bounds, say $\frac12x^2(\frac1a+\frac1b)<a+b-d < 2x$.

Answer (score 1):

Due to Pythagoras, $d = \sqrt{a^2-x^2} + \sqrt{b^2-x^2}$. However, $a - \sqrt{a^2-x^2} $ goes faster to zero than $x$ for $x\to 0$:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x}=0,$$
so your inequality does not hold for small $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No. The inequality $x\le a+b-d$ does not hold for $(a,b,d)=(9,2,10)$ because
$$x=\frac{\sqrt{(a+b+d)(a+b-d)(a+d-b)(b+d-a)}}{2d}=\frac{3\sqrt{119}}{20}\gt \frac{3\sqrt{49}}{20}= \frac{21}{20}\gt 1.$$